# String to Double converting isn't working

Tags: vb.net, string, double

I have a very strange problem: It seems that when I try to convert a string (in double format) to a double/decimal that it isn't working.

I have a string input for example

- 240mm Blue Window
- 2.5mm Black Lower Part

Where I take out the double part with the working code:

```
tempmm = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value
tempmm = tempmm.Substring(0, tempmm.IndexOf("mm"))
```

Now I have "240" and "2.5" and I want to convert this string to a double.
I tried this with these 2 examples, but when doing this however, my 240 becomes 240.0, but my 2.5 becomes 25.0 (!)

```
tempdouble = Convert.ToDouble(tempmm)
Double.TryParse(tempmm, tempdouble)
```

Any idea?

[image]

Comment: I assume it's a localization problem. Here, if I do Double.Parse("2,5") it will return 25.0

Comment: Use a comma as is common in countries like Belgium and Holland.  Or use the TryParse overload that takes CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.  Do not forget to check the return value of TryParse().

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to 2,5 and now it is working
tempmm = tempmm.Replace(".", ",")

I voted you both up, but I don't have the option to mark this as the correct answer. Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Replacing the decimal points with a comma is not a good solution.  You should do as Hans says and use the correct overload of the TryParse method so you don't have to resort to a wasteful string replace.

Comment: It was working with the replacement, but I changed it now like you suggested, and that is also working. Thanks